# Can a CNN recognize the difference in size if the images are the same?

Tags: image, size, conv-neural-network, convolution

Could a CNN tell the difference between different size range of the same organism? Like a puppy vs a adult or a child vs an adult? Or more like a large fly vs a small fly, where they look identical but one is just larger than the other?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question to answer but usually theoretical CNN is able to do. It is mainly dependent on the training data itself. In case of a child vs adult, you can gather a dataset that includes alot of variances in sizes and ages in order to make sure that you will have CNN model that able to find patterns and generalize at the end. At the end, the CNN will learn many other features that make the classification scale or size invariant (In dependent of Size) such as shapes,colors, clothes and face features ....etc. Such Intra-class classification problems, it is not easily tackled with traditional supervised learning and therefore some researchers are applying an approach called "[Deep Metric Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6622)".

> Metric learning is the task of learning a distance function over objects. A metric or distance function has to obey four axioms: non-negativity, identity of indiscernibles, symmetry and subadditivity (or the triangle inequality). In practice, metric learning algorithms ignore the condition of identity of indiscernibles and learn a pseudo-metric.[Wiki Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning)

[image: Example for Metric Learning]

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to differentiate the metric that you mention in the question. At first, it is a different task to recognize age and size.

About the age, yes, it is doable. For deep learning-based approach, you will need appropriate data. For non-training based approach (old-school image processing), you would need to create some metrics for each object based on age (counting the wrinkle, white hair etc. for humans)

About the size, unfortunately, it is still under research and it is not clear to mention if it is properly doable or not. Whenever we mention object size recognition from a single image, there are more things to consider. The first thing is the perspective. If the object found in the image is large with respect to the image coordinates, is it close to the camera, even though its size is tiny, hence, it is showing as large or it is really huge but too far away from the camera? Such a problem may be overcome by knowing the object geometry in prior and by developing an algorithm based on that geometry along with deep learning. However, current deep learning technology is not accurate enough to distinguish the dimensions and location, hence object geometry precisely yet. 
Another alternative would be to control the environment. For example, if you know that both objects lie on the same plane (i.e. on the table, next to each other) in the real world, the rest is a trivial problem to resolve.